# Downloaded Fyne GUI package for GoLang but import statements won't work

Tags: go, user-interface, import, fyne

I am using the Fyne GUI package for Go for a project.

I imported the package using the import statements recommended on the Fyne website.

import (

```
// "fmt"
"image"
"image/color"
"image/draw"
"image/png"
"math"
"os"
"time"

"fyne.io/fyne"
"fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
"fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
"fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
```

)

at first I didn't download the package, thinking it would imported from the web, not understanding how fyne or Go worked completely.

[image: command line commands used to download fyne]

[image: command line results downloading packages for fyne]

[image: fyne package downloaded to my hard drive]

my compiler complains of a broken import

[image: compiler error messages]

Comment: Please take a tutorial first, for example, https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing v2 APIs with the old v1. See how your first import does not include “/v2”.

If changing that does not resolve the issue make sure you have run “go mod tidy”.

Comment: does it matter the directory in which I run that command.  I added "/v2" at the end of the first import statements.

Comment: As long as you are inside the project structure it will work.

Comment: Does that mean the same directory as the source code?

Comment: Do I need to copy "fyne.io" into the same directory as my code?"

Comment: No - there is no need to copy the code. Just run “go mod tidy” anywhere inside your project.